# In Django create a model method which determines an id for all objects that share the same foreign key

Tags: python, django, django-models

Kind of new to Django and while trying to create my first own project, i stumbled upon a problem.
I have two different model classes: `Star` and `Planet`. Each planet has a foreignkey which belongs to a Star. Now I would like to have a field for `Planet`, which is basically the id/pk for its star system that is given on creation/discovery. All known planets of the star system already have their star system id and thus the newly created/discovered planet would require an id that is incremented on the last id that was given.

| Id | Star | Id in Star System | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sun | 1 | Neptune |
| 2 | Alpha Centauri | 1 | Hoth |
| 3 | Alpha Centauri | 2 | Coruscant |
| 4 | Sun | 2 | Earth |
| 5 | Sun | 3 | Jupiter |
| 6 | Alpha Centauri | 3 | Yavin4 |
| 7 | Sun | 4 | Venus |

My models are looking like this

models.py:

```
class Star(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Planet(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   star = models.ForeignKey(Star, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

   def starSystemPlanetId(self):
      What could work in here?
```

This new Id should be available to be called in a template like this:

```
{% for planets in object_list %}
    <li> 
         <p>Planet {{planets.name}} is the Nr. {{planets.customer_id}} planet of the star system</p>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

I have learned already, that business logic should be implemented inside `models.py` via a model method.

```
def starSystemPlanetId(self, star_var):
   starSystemPlanetId = Planet.objects.filter(star = star_var).filter(pk >> earlierPlanetsPk).count()
   return starSystemPlanetId
```

Maybe there is a standard query function available for this kind of problem already.

Comment: IMO, it kinda depends on what you need. You need to consider all CRUD operations and how does that affect your ID. For example, what happens if you delete a planet from a star system? Do you want the ID of later added planets to shift for one down automatically, or remain the same because the ID is used for some kind of referencing. Secondly, you need to consider how are you using your ID. Just for display, or for ordering, or maybe search? The solution could be having your ID stored in the DB or calculating it dynamically like you're doing.

Comment: Also, for the calculation of the ID in a method, maybe having `created_at` and `updated_at` timestamps would be handy.

Comment: Yeah the deletion is important to consider if you think about what happened to Pluto. Its a project for me and more or less to understand how to handle information that can be derived from multiple models and fields. In this case botch options would be very interesting.

Comment: So, do you know for what do you need this ID? Is it just for displaying the order in which the planets are added to the star system?

Comment: Yes it is purely to display it in some template

Answer (score 0):

This is my suggestion (following the comments on you post):

```py
class Planet(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    star = models.ForeignKey(Star, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='planets')

    # Use property since it's more pythonic
    @property
    def star_system_planet_id(self):
       """0-based display identifier for a planet in the start system."""
        # No need for the 'star_var' variable since you already have it in the 
        # model instance
        return self.star.planets.filter(pk__lt=self.pk).count()
```

Small note: the property won't work for objects that have not been stored in the DB cause they don't have the PK assigned yet. For this, you probably want to return an empty string or `None`, etc. Up to you.